# What are my VPN options?

Tags: vpn, tunneling

We are changing ISPs and at the last minute the new company is refusing to set up a critical VPN tunnel that we currently have.

Data comes into our office via a line into an ISP controlled firewall and then from there it goes into our bank of switches. Currently that firewall has the VPN settings that create a tunnel to a 3rd party office that hosts our website servers, allowing any computers on our local network to communicate with the web servers without anything having to be set up on each one.

The new ISP is refusing to create the VPN unless they have their own hardware on both ends. Is there a way for me to set up the VPN from "inside" their firewall, so that we can have the same functionality?

Comment: Do you get a public IP address from the ISP?

Comment: Yes, I have a list of public IPs that will be ours.

Comment: What type of VPN tunnel is it?  What hardware is at the other end?

Comment: This is where we quickly get beyond my knowledge/understanding - I'm not sure what "type" you're looking for - does IPSEC-ISAKMP with ESP-3DES-MD5 tell you what you need to know? I'm not sure what the firewall device on the 3rd party side is, but I can try to find out if it is useful/necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can run an ipsec VPN through the ISP managed firewall only if they configure it for VPN passthrough.  This entails allowing the following traffic:

> Internet Protocol Security (IPSec) uses IP protocol 50 for Encapsulated Security Protocol         >(ESP),IP protocol 51 for Authentication Header (AH), and UDP port 500 for IKE Phase 1 negotiation and >Phase 2 negotiations. UDP ports 500 and 4500 are used, if NAT-T is used for IKE Phase 1 negotiation >and Phase 2 negotiations
>   http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB5671

Comment: Sorry that I'm not up to speed on this stuff, I have very little networking experience. Reading through that link - it talks about a NetScreen-Remote VPN Client that I would need to purchase to "run" the ipsec VPN. It seems to me like this is something that I would need to have on every computer that needs to connect across the VPN, is this correct? Is there a way/device that would allow for everything on our local network to communicate across the VPN?

Comment: Ignore the link - it refers to specific hardware implementations.  What I was trying to say is yes, you can set up an IPsec VPN across the ISP controlled firewall IF they allow the traffic through.  Also, not being funny, but if you have very little networking experience why is it your responsibility to set up a site to site VPN?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Any recommendations on the best way to go about setting up the IPsec VPN from inside the firewall? I believe they will open any ports on it that I tell them to - they just won't do the VPN settings themselves.   We're a smaller company and we don't have a real network/system admin. I've got the most experience with hardware in general, so it's become my duty to figure this out.

Comment: In general, acquire a hardware that can run the VPN, (eg. prosumer router), plug it in and set it up on one of your public IPs, then configure the VPN in collaboration with the remote third party.

Comment: Ok, just want to make sure I'm understanding the new network layout correctly. I would put the new router between the ISP firewall device and our switches and then reconfigure our default gateway address to be the router's IP instead of the firewall, yes?